# prevent a modal from closing after a submit inside the modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

i have a form inside the modal .. after submitting it must show a table inside the modal. how to let the modal opened after that?
here is a piece of the modal.

```
  <div id="AddModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

           <div class="modal-header text-center">
            ...
            </div>

                <!---- modal body ---->

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="form1">
                    <input type="text" name="searchinput">
                    <input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="search">
                </form>
                    <?php 
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['btnSearch']))
                        {
                            require_once("connection.php");
                            $table= getFood($_REQUEST['searchinput']);
                            echo $table;
                        }
                    ?>

            </div>
```

i tried javascript like:

```
       $('#form1').on('submit', function(e){
           $('#AddModal').modal('show');
           e.preventDefault();
       });
```

didnt work.

Comment: you need to submit your form using ajax, then the modal will not close

Comment: i dont know much about ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
echo '<script>$("#AddModal").modal("show'");</script>';
```

Before

```
echo $table;
```

in your php code